# Nancy test method returning [Err!] for response body

Tags: nancy

I'm new to developing with the Nancy, and I'm stumped as to why the response body to my test method is returning "[ERR!]" as opposed to the markup that I'm expecting.

```
    private BrowserResponse _response;

    [Test]
    public void GetLoginIsOk()
    {
        var accountDatabase = new AccountDatabase();
        var loginModule = new LoginModule(accountDatabase);
        var browser = new Browser(c => c.Module(loginModule));

        _response = browser.Get("/login");
        _response.StatusCode.ShouldBe(HttpStatusCode.OK);

        Console.Write(_response.Body.AsString());
    }
```

The test is passing (i.e. the status code returned is OK).  But, I'd like to do additional validation on the markup returned so that the expected form fields do in fact exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out what my issue was. I had set up a master page and forgot to set that to copy out to the output directory.

Answer (score 2):

To test the mark-up can use selectors to query the body, like so:

```
_response.Body["#someelement"].ShouldExist();
```

See the [documentation](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Testing-your-application) for details

Comment: I should have indicated in my original post that my initial attempt included your statement above. When the statement failed, I started examining the body of the response and found that it only contained "[ERR!]".  I have used Console.Write(_response.Body.AsString()) in another test and verified that the markup returned was indeed what I expected.  I guess at this point, I'm just trying to get some guidance as to where I should start to try and track where my issue is occurring because everything is executing as it should when I'm stepping through my code and the response code returned is OK.